# Get PostGIS geometry data and display it on map using GetMapRequest

Tags: postgresql, wms, vector, java, getmap

How can I get the data from PostgreSQL db and display on map using GetMapRequest?

- I have done connecting the PostgreSQL db which contains the geometry data.
- Now I want to redirect that data to map using GetMapRequest from my Java code.
- As GetMapRequest returns a raster image in response. So, how it would
  be done using the GetMapRequest in Java?

Comment: have a look at [GeoTools](http://geotools.org)

Comment: @IanTurton Can i use the geotools GetMapRequest service to get the vector data and display it on map? Is it possible?

Comment: If it must be vector data then you need a WFS (which GeoTools can do) as getMapRequest is a WMS call and will return an image. GeoTools will talk directly to your postgis db too.  Please edit your question to narrow it down

Comment: @IanTurton I actually want to return the image by sending a getMapRequest to my postgisdb which contains the vector data. Any possible way for doing that?

Comment: please edit your question to make it clearer

Comment: @IanTurton Edited

Comment: I meant, could you expand your question to explain what you are trying to do, what you have tried already etc

Comment: @IanTurton Alright

Answer (score 1):

You seem confused about how GeoTools works, you can make a `getMap` request using the [`gt-wms` module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/wms/wms.html) to fetch an image of a map from a WMS server (like [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org), [MapServer](http://mapserver.org) or [QgisServer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/index.html)). If you are more interested in actual vectors then you could use the [`gt-wfs-ng`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs-ng.html) module to make a `getFeatures` request to a WFS server (all the previous mentioned servers support WFS too).

However if you want to fetch vector data from a datastore (e.g. PostGIS, Oracle, Shapefiles, GeoJSON files etc) you will need to create a datastore of the relevant type. This will allow your program to read the data and allow you to carry out analysis or renderer it to a map. The GeoTools [quickstart tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html) covers this.

However, from your [other questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290745/how-can-i-create-my-own-wms-server), I suspect you are trying to write a new WMS server from scratch in which case you will need to fetch the data from PostGIS (using a [PostGIS datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html)), reproject ([CRS modules](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/index.html)) it if necessary and then render it to an image (see the [rendering module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/index.html)) having taken any styling into account (see the [styling module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/xml/style.html)). You will also need to write some code to parse and understand the WMS getMap requests that you receive (for some pointers you can look at GeoServer's [GetMapKvpRequestReader](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/map/GetMapKvpRequestReader.java)).